# Using a setTimeout in a async function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, settimeout, axios

I have a async function that waits for an axios call to complete before proceeding. The problem is that I need to put a timeout on the axios call to half a second so that I don't hit the shopify API call limit.

```
async function processMatchingSchools(customer_metafield_url) {
  for (const item of customer_metafield_url) {
    await axios.get(item).then((res) => {
      for (key in res.data.metafields) {
        if (res.data.metafields[key].value === schoolName) {
          id_for_each_student.push(shopifyAdmin + "/customers/" + res.data.metafields[key].owner_id + "/metafields.json")
        }
      }
    })
  }
  console.log("Customer metafields to search", id_for_each_student)
  processOwnerIds(id_for_each_student)
}
```

when I try putting a setTimeout, it calls the setTimeout and moves on before completing the axios calls.

```
async function processMatchingSchools(customer_metafield_url) {
  for (const item of customer_metafield_url) {
    await setTimeout(function(item) {
      axios.get(item).then((res) => {
        for (key in res.data.metafields) {
          if (res.data.metafields[key].value === schoolName) {
            id_for_each_student.push(shopifyAdmin + "/customers/" + res.data.metafields[key].owner_id + "/metafields.json")
          }
        }
      })
    }, 500)
  }
  console.log("Customer metafields to search", id_for_each_student)
  processOwnerIds(id_for_each_student)
}
```

Any help?

Comment: Well, setTimeout isn't promised based, so trying to await for it is slightly odd.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`setTimeout()` doesn't return a `Promise`, but you can wrap it in one like this. I also cleaned up the rest of your code a little.

```js
async function processMatchingSchools(customer_metafield_url) {
  for (const item of customer_metafield_url) {
    await new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(resolve, 500)
    })

    const { data: { metafields } } = await axios.get(item)

    for (const { value, owner_id } of Object.values(metafields)) {
      if (value === schoolName) {
        id_for_each_student.push(`${shopifyAdmin}/customers/${owner_id}/metafields.json`)
      }
    }
  }

  console.log("Customer metafields to search", id_for_each_student)

  processOwnerIds(id_for_each_student)
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping me out :P And thank-you Patrick for helping me clean my newbie code.

Answer (score 46):

`await` only works on promises.
You need to wrap `setTimeout` in a promise:

```
const waitFor = delay => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delay));

await waitFor(500);
```

Answer (score 9):

setTimeout does not return a promise so cannot be `await`ed.

You could create your own promise-based `setTimeout` and use that.

```
const setTimeoutPromise = timeout => new Promise(resolve => {        
  setTimeout(resolve, timeout);
});

await setTimeoutPromise(500);
```

Answer (score 6):

Create a `sleep` function that returns a promise that you can use, like so:

```
const sleep = (milliseconds=500) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds))
```

And to use it in an async function:

```
(async () => {
  console.log("function invoked...")
  await sleep(500)
  console.log("I got here about 500 milliseconds later")
})()
```

Comment: it should be `const sleep = ms => {return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));} `

Answer (score 4):

You need to to create new promise for example like that

```
function delay(ms){
 return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
}
```

And then use it in your code before calling API

```
...
await delay(500)
await axios.get(item).then((res) => {
...
```

Answer (score 3):

I created `setTimeout2` function that works the same just as a promise:

```
const setTimeout2 = (callback, ms) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
    callback();
    resolve();
  }, ms));
}
```

So, altogether (noticed the setTimeout**2** change):

```
async function processMatchingSchools(customer_metafield_url) {
  for (const item of customer_metafield_url) {
    await setTimeout2(function(item) {
      axios.get(item).then((res) => {
        for (key in res.data.metafields) {
          if (res.data.metafields[key].value === schoolName) {
            id_for_each_student.push(shopifyAdmin + "/customers/" + res.data.metafields[key].owner_id + "/metafields.json")
          }
        }
      })
    }, 500)
  }
  console.log("Customer metafields to search", id_for_each_student)
  processOwnerIds(id_for_each_student)
}
```